# What does “still informant” mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

With his ideas still informant, Albert Einstein was 22 years old when he sat out alone on foot across the Alps.

Comment: Who knows? Bad translation, I'd guess.

Comment: The quote originates from a single article, and I don't see the phrase "still informant" used in a similar sense anywhere else. I suspect the writer meant to write something like "stll in forming".

Comment: Perhaps the author meant "inchoate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regular formation from the primary meaning of

> **Inform**: 
>   **I**, 2. (obelised as obsolete) *intransitive* to take shape; to form. -***1652***  (*Shorter Oxford*)

The  -ant ending is a present participle.  Therefore

**Informant** adj. taking shape.  -2015(?) (obsolete?)

Equally it is properly formed, & accurately derived from the Latin:    (Ainsworth, Thesaurus; who gives a quotation from Cicero to justify (2))

> **Informo** -are, act. (1) *to form, shape*, or *fashion*. (2) *to contrive or design in the mind.*